# How to install Ruby with rvm on Windows 10 with Cygwin64 Terminal?

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to install Ruby on a Windows 10 using the Cygwin64 Terminal so that I can us RVM to manage my Ruby version and gems. This is a first time install so I do not have any Ruby currently. Every time I try to run rvm install 2.1.7 the process errors out on compiling. Below is a screen shot of the terminal window:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dX7P4.png)

Comment: Don't know enough about C & compiling ruby to say, but I feel like it's missing something in the dependencies that you install when you setup cygwin. Kinda like Pedro said, RailsInstaller is the way to go. Just harder to maintain separate versions of ruby. Given most rails apps are running on linux servers, i'd suggest maybe trying something like vagrant, or developing in linux virtual machine instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Nowadays (2021) the best way to go is not to use Cygwin but rather WSL2. Then you have plenty of tools since you basically have a Linux install. [rvm](https://rvm.io/), [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) should be able to do the job.

Old answer:
Best way is to use [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en). It handles most dependencies for you. I wouldn't mess around with RVM in Windows, AFAICT you will have issues along the road trying to use it on a non-UNIX environment.

Comment: I am not completely sold on Cygwin64 and agree that RailsInstaller works great. Is there any way on Win10 to use gem setts or does my gem file take care of this? I would like to be able to play around with Rails 5 and some other gems but not have them conflict with my main project and its gems. Thanks for the input @Pedro and @agmcleod!

Comment: Nowadays with bundler these issues are much harder to come by. You should be fine. I haven't used gemsets in years.

Comment: Very cool. That was the only reason that I looking at Cygwin64. Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://railsinstaller.org/ is no longer available, any alternative to get the rvm on windows